# Shared code but need different results depending upon which Client executed

Tags: c#, .net

I have been asked to work on a solution that has 3 projects. 2 separate clients and 1 common code project. In the common code project (that is shared between the 2 clients) I need to have a method that returns slightly different results depending upon which client is executing.

I could do a partial class to get around this. Is there another way that might be better?

I cannot refactor the solution to separate the projects completely :-(

Answer (score 3):

Pass an extra parameter to this method that tells it how to behave and call it differently from each client.

Comment: In this case , your answer looks fine , but what if you have no idea how many future clients will be, will you go back and change base code every time you have new client

Comment: @SurjitSamra - If you rely on a function to behave differently for each client, you need to do something. You can, in fact, pass in the needed behaviour directly from the client (either using polymorphism or passing in a delegate).